# Puppet in operator

Tags: puppet

I'm writing a conditional statement in Puppet (3.7) that tests whether the hostname is in a defined array of hostnames. If true, the class continues to run, if not, it exits with the 
fail function

```
if $::hostname in $approved_hosts != str2bool("true") {
  fail("This module is for approved reposync hosts only")
```

Where $approved_hosts is an array of hostnames. This method does not work, but if I change $approved_hosts to ['hostname1', 'hostname2'] it does work:

```
if $::hostname in ['hostname1', 'hostname2'] != str2bool("true") {
  fail("This module is for approved reposync hosts only")
```

Can anyone explain why when I convert the array of hostnames to a variable the condition fails but works otherwise?

Thanks :)

Comment: Why do you perform that `str2bool("true")` dance? Why not just `if condition { ... }` ?

Comment: It's not required and the in operator is supposed to return the booleon true if the value left of the in operator is in the value of the right, which it is.

I was just using the st2bool function is stdlib as more of a santity check. I have since remove that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust your code (fail to notify), did the test in a test.pp file, it runs fine.

```
  $approved_hosts = ['hostname1', 'hostname2']
  if $::hostname in $approved_hosts != str2bool("true")
   { notify {"This module is for approved reposync hosts only":} }
```

So that means your code is no problem at array define, it should be something else.

Comment: Thanks. That does work and I havent tested this in a few days but the issue seems to arise when the value of $approved_hosts is defined in a different file (params.pp)

Puppet has no issues finding the reference and Geppetto shows it being properly resolved. There is just a runtime issue I have yet to spend the time debugging. Thanks :)